# PhoneGap for android- Camera API .. Not working with Jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new learner with Phonegap and JqueryMobile. I have made separate project in eclipse with  just phonegap Camera API code. Its working fine in emulator. But when I integrate same code in another project with Jquery mobile, it is throwing exception **(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PNG' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:347)**. Without this camera api code is working fine.

**(1) Working code- just phonegap**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
    var encodingType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        console.log("onDeviceReady1");

        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        console.log("onDeviceReady2");
        encodingType=navigator.camera.EncodingType;

    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
      console.log(imageData);
      var re = /\?(\d*)$/;
      imageData=imageData.replace(re, "");
      alert("imageData is "+imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
      console.log(imageURI);
      // alert("uri is "+imageURI);
      var re = /\?(\d*)$/;
      imageURI=imageURI.replace(re, "");
      alert("imageURI is "+imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI; 
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1, encodingType:encodingType.PNG });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, allowEdit: true, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1 ,encodingType:encodingType.PNG, }); 
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) { 
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1 , 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,encodingType:PNG,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="a.png" />
    <img style="" id="largeImage" src="a.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**(2) Not Working code- jquerymobile + phonegap**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>
        <script src="jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
    var encodingType; // sets the format of returned value 

    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        console.log("onDeviceReady1");

        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        console.log("onDeviceReady2");
        encodingType=navigator.camera.EncodingType;

    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
      console.log(imageData);
      var re = /\?(\d*)$/;
      imageData=imageData.replace(re, "");
      alert("imageData is "+imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
      console.log(imageURI);
      // alert("uri is "+imageURI);
      var re = /\?(\d*)$/;
      imageURI=imageURI.replace(re, "");
      alert("imageURI is "+imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI; 
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1, encodingType:encodingType.PNG });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality:50, destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) { 
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1 , 
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,encodingType:PNG,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    // 
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }

    </script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">        
        </script>
        <script src="local.js">
        </script>
        <script src="jqm.autoComplete.min-1.4.2.js">
        </script>
        <script src="camera.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <script>
    var Countrydata='';
        $("#page1").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
            var myXML = ""
            var  availableTags = "";
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "Countries.xml", true);
                request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                            myXML = request.responseXML;                    
                            parseXml(myXML);
                        }
                    }

                }
                request.send();


                function parseXml(xml) {


                    $(xml).find('Country').each(function(){

                    if(Countrydata !='')
                    {
                    Countrydata += ',';
                    }
                    Countrydata += $(this).text();
                    });

                    availableTags = Countrydata;

                }

            availableTags = ['India'];

            $("#searchinput1").autocomplete({
                target: $('#suggestions'),
                source: availableTags,              
                minLength: 1,
                matchFromStart: false,
                 callback: function(e) {

                    var $a = $(e.currentTarget); // access the selected item
                    $('#searchinput1').val($a.text()); // place the value of the selection into the search box
                    $("#searchinput1").autocomplete('clear'); // clear the listview
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h2>
                    Nalco Water Savings Unit
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" data-theme="b">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"   data-icon="arrow-r" >
                                Customer Info
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page2"   data-icon="arrow-r">
                                Additional Details
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page3"   data-icon="info">
                                Summary
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <div data-role="collapsible-set"   data-content-theme="b">
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                        <h3>
                            Company details
                        </h3>
                                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="textinput3">
                            Company number
                        </label>
                        <input name="txtCompNumber" id="textinput3" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="textinput4">
                            Company Address
                        </label>
                        <input name="txtCompAddr" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput5">
                                City
                            </label>
                            <input name="txtCity" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="searchinput1">
                            Country
                        </label>
                        <input  id="searchinput1" placeholder="...Serach for country"  type="text" />

                        <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
               </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                        <h3>
                            Customer Name
                        </h3>
                         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                                <label for="textinput1">
                                    Customer Name
                                </label>
                                <input name="txtCustName" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                        <h3>
                            Sales Engineer Details
                        </h3>

                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                                    <label for="textinput6">
                                        Sales Engineer Name
                                    </label>
                                    <input name="txtSalesEngName" id="textinput6" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                                    <label for="textinput7">
                                        Sales Engineer Phone No.
                                    </label>
                                    <input name="txtSalesEngPhone" id="textinput7" placeholder="" value="" type="tel" />
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" href="#page2">
                    Proceed
                </a>


            </div>

        </div>


          <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="b">

            <div   data-role="header">
                <h2>
                    Nalco Water Savings Unit
                </h2>
            </div>
              <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page1"   data-icon="arrow-r" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                                Customer Info
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"   data-icon="arrow-r">
                                Additional Details
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page3"   data-icon="info">
                                Summary
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <h2> <b> What additional installation costs have been identified? </b> </h2>
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" >
                 <div class="ui-grid-b" id="gridAddCost">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <h3><b>Description</b></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" >
                    <h3><b>Cost</b></h3>
                    </div>
                     <div class="ui-block-c" >                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input name="txt1" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input name="txt2" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                     <div class="ui-block-c" >                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input name="txt3" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input name="txt4" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                     <div class="ui-block-c" >                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <input name="txt5" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <input name="txt6" id="textinput5" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-c" >                   
                    </div>                  
                </div>


   <input id="btnAddDesc" type="button" value="Add installation" />

                </fieldset>

                     <a data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" href="#page3">
                    Proceed
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>

          <div data-role="page" id="page3" data-theme="b">

            <div   data-role="header">
                <h2>
                    Nalco Water Savings Unit
                </h2>
            </div>
              <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

                <div data-role="content">   
             <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="a.png" />
    <img style="" id="largeImage" src="a.png" />
                </div><!-- /content -->
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page1"   data-icon="arrow-r" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">
                                Customer Info
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#page2"   data-icon="arrow-r">
                                Additional Details
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"   data-icon="info">
                                Summary
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                     <a data-role="button" data-inline="true"  data-rel="back" data-transition="fade" href="#page1">
                    Proceed
                </a>
            </div>
         </div>

        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This method:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1 , 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,encodingType:PNG,
    sourceType: source });
```

Should be:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100, targetWidth: -1, targetHeight: -1 , 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType:navigator.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    sourceType: source });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.(I am missing visual studio intellisense here :)) but now, I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/camera.js:60 error. Same code in different separate project works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem using

```
(quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, targetWidth: 1153, targetHeight: 385)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you forget to include the image files a.png?

```
<img style="width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="a.png" />
<img style="" id="largeImage" src="a.png" />
```

as per your code it should be there in the same directory where your index.html is

Comment: strange .. I m getting another error now.. ** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPicture' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/camera.js:60 ** .. Also, i noticed it is problem with jquery  mobile only..

Comment: Or may just i m on emulator, it is not allowing me to call this camera function? But in other case why it does not show error then? :(

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here ,

You have added

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>` in your HTML file.

It should be like this

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>`

It means you have to save your **cordova-2.0.0.js** at `assets/www/js` dir. or download latest [Cordova](http://phonegap.com/install/) and save it locally.

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Open the console, go to the project directory. Type at the console:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

Make sure your cordova instalation has needed plugin.
If The required plugin not installed, type:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

Then, re-run that application on physical Device, do not use Emulator. Emulator has no camera.
I use jQm too, there is no problem between cordova media plugin and jQm.